# java : search for substring in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to look for substrings in the elasticsearch, but what I've come to known and what I've coded doesn't exactly look for a substring like the way I want.

Here's what I've coded :

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = new BoolQueryBuilder();
            query.must(new QueryStringQueryBuilder("tagName : *"+tagName+"*"));

            SearchResponse response = esclient.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(type)
                    .setQuery(query)
                    .execute().actionGet();

            SearchHit[] hits = response.getHits().getHits();


            for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
                Map map = hit.getSource();
                list.add((String) map.get("tagName"));
            }

            list = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {;
                jsonArrayBuilder.add((String) list.get(i));
            }
```

What I'm trying to implement is to look even if part of the given tagname matches with anything should be listed.

But in case, for ex : if I'm looking for a tag named "social_security_number" and I type "social security" then I would like it to be listed.
But what's actually happening is if I miss the underscore, it's not getting listed.
Is it possible to be done? Should I modify this code to search that way?

Here is my index structure :

```
POST arempris/emptagnames
{
  "mappings" : {
    "emptags":{
          "properties": {
                "employeeid": {
                  "type":"integer"
                },
                "tagName": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fielddata": true,
                  "analyzer": "lowercase_keyword",
                  "search_analyzer": "lowercase_keyword"
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Would greatly appreciate for your help and thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analyzer that you have set does not tokenize anything, so the space is important. Specifying a custom analyzer that will split on whitespaces and underscores and anything you might find useful is a good solution. The below will work, but check really carefully what the analyzer does and visit the documentation for every part you don't understand.

```
PUT stackoverflow
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "customanalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "standard",
            "generatewordparts"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "generatewordparts": {
          "type": "word_delimiter",
          "split_on_numerics": false,
          "split_on_case_change": false,
          "generate_word_parts": true,
          "generate_number_parts": false,
          "stem_english_possessive": false,
          "catenate_all": false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "emptags": {
      "properties": {
        "employeeid": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "tagName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true,
          "analyzer": "customanalyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "customanalyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET stackoverflow/emptags/1
{
  "employeeid": 1,
  "tagName": "social_security_number"
}

GET stackoverflow/_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "customanalyzer",
  "text" : "social_security_number123"
}

GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "tagName",
      "query": "*curi*"
    }
  }
}
```

Another solution would be to normalize your input and replace any symbol that you want to treat as a whitespace (e.g. underscore) with a whitespace.

Read here for more

- http://nocf-www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html

Comment: It really helped me, thanks a lot for the response and the documentation references you have mentioned! :)

Comment: No problem, have fun